# Adding button before input form with Bootsrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, input

I'm trying to make this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhW62.png

looking like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0cuT.png

The "input-group-addon" class of Bootstrap seems to be exactly what I'm looking for but I'm not getting the result I want since the input form widens to the whole width of the window as in here:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="" method="get">
        <h4> 
            Find in 
            <div class="input-group"> 
                <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"></span> 
                <input type="text" name="in" id="searchTextField" class="form-control" value="London"> 
            </div>           
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>                         
        </h4> 
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the original code of the 1st screenshot:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="" method="get">
        <h4> 
            Find in   
            <input type="text" name="in" id="searchTextField" class="form-control" value="London">          
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>                         
        </h4> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the `input-group` class. It has a style of `display: table` to attach and align your addon to the input field. A way to get around this is to add a wrapper div around your input-group div. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e9Hem/)

Note that I made the styling only active at 768px and larger. I did this to match the functionality of the example you gave. You can remove this and it will always be triggered, whether smaller or larger screen sizes.

HTML

```
<div class="text-center">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="" method="get">
        <h4> 
            Find in 
            <div class="input-group-fix">
                <div class="input-group"> 
                    <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"></span> 
                    <input type="text" name="in" id="searchTextField" class="form-control" value="London"/> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>                         
        </h4> 
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .input-group-fix {
        display: inline-table;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Changed inline-block to inline-table, as it works in both Firefox and Chrome. It also appears to be a better solution as `input-group` uses a table display with table-cells.

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e9Hem/2/)

You can also check out the differences between the display types [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unluckily that is working on Firefox but not on Chrome :( Do you know why? Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that, I only checked it in Firefox. It seems that using `display: inline-table` instead of `display: inline-block` works in both Firefox and Chrome. It is actually a better solution since input-groups are already displayed as a table with table-cells. http://jsfiddle.net/e9Hem/2/ - Updated demo.